# Regular expression to match block of HTML

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

First I'll show you a sample of the code I'm working with:

```
<div class="entry">
        <p>Any HTML content could go here!</p>
      </div>
    </div><!--/post -->
```

Normally I'd use a regex rule such as the following to look for a prefix and a suffix and grab everything in between:

```
(?<=<div class="entry">).*(?=</div><!--/post -->)
```

However, that doesnt appear to be working as it seems to be pulling the white space in between then following parts instead of the HTML content itself:

```
<div class="entry">
        <p>
```

Any help/suggestions would be much appreciated as I've been bashing my head with this one for a good few hours now.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I should also note, the HTML content between "<div class="entry">" and "</div><!--/post -->" is multi-line.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best methods to parse HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3577641/best-methods-to-parse-html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Don't use Regex to parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags). You need an Xml Parser or similar.

Search Stackoverflow for the best one, like so: [Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php)

Comment: Thankyou, that nudge in the right direction was much appreciated.

Comment: Would this work for grabbing multiple instances of the above desired HTML?  I was planning to use the expression with preg_match_all to grab the lot and put it into an array ready for insert to a database.

Comment: +1 Nice answer and response from OP - not everyone appreciates an answer of 'NO!'

Answer (score -1):

You can also consider php [strip_tags()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).