# Stuck with php regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match-all

So I have been trying to figure out regex to capture multiple sections of my data but, seems I've been failing since last two days now...:(

Please help
Let's say following is my data :

```
<div class="tabs_container">
<ul class="tabs">
    ##BEGINLOOP##gAs##
        <li><a href="#">##title##</a></li>
    ##ENDLOOP##
</ul>
    ##BEGINLOOP##LI##
    <div class="tabs_content">##title## is ##content##</div>
    ##ENDLOOP##
</div>
```

and i want to capture following group:

1. The text before ##BEGINLOOP##
2. The text after ##BEGINLOOP## and before ##(gAs in first and LI in second)
3. Text After ##ENDLOOP##

I have been trying various regex combination but nothing worked for giving me the exact solution.
 This was my last try

```
'/(?:##BEGINLOOP##)([a-z|A-Z]*)##(.+?)(?=##ENDLOOP##)(?:##ENDLOOP##)/s'
```

I am using PHP preg_match_all function

Please help ?

Comment: Duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5727185/regular-expression-to-match-block-of-html?rq=1

Comment: It's not a duplicate, The added post is about HTML parsing, where as this is about PHP parsing...

Comment: Check again, they both relate to "How to parse HTML using PHP", only the HTML code to parse changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex is close to be right. Just a few notes:

`[a-z|A-Z]` does not mean what you think it means. It means *accept all chars from a to z, and the char |, and all chars from A to Z*. You want `[a-zA-Z]`.

`(?=##ENDLOOP##)` means that the next group matches only if preceded by `##ENDLOOP##`, so `##ENDLOOP##` will match only if preceded by `##ENDLOOP##`. You may want to remove `(?=##ENDLOOP##)`.

This works:

```
'/(?:##BEGINLOOP##)([a-zA-Z]*)##(.+?)(?:##ENDLOOP##)/s'
```

Try it here: http://3v4l.org/aCvvY

If you also want to also capture the parts outside of ##BEGINLOOP##...##ENDLOOP##, for the whole document, preg_split does the work:

```
$parts = preg_split('/(?:##BEGINLOOP##)([a-zA-Z]*)##(.+?)(?:##ENDLOOP##)/s', $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
```

Try it here: http://3v4l.org/LWaQS

Comment: My problem is not with that part, the problem is i am unable to capture the group outside the ##BEGINLOOP##...##ENDLOOP## ..?

Comment: Added a `preg_split` example that does just that.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
preg_match('@(.*?)##BEGINLOOP##(.*?)##(.*?)##ENDLOOP##(.*?)@s', $data, $matches);

var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: This doesn't make the correct group, in first group it gives me `<div class="tabs_container">
<ul class="tabs">
 ##BEGINLOOP##gAs##
  <li><a href="#">##title##</a></li>
 ##ENDLOOP##`